# Custom Join request on LoRaWAN End Node STM32L0

Tags: stm32, self-join, lorawan, stm32ldiscovery

I want to make my end node send join requests to the gateway continuously.

My goal is to send join requests continuously until the end node connected to the gateway, and if the connection is broken after joining, then it should again send join requests contiguously.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We would need much more information regarding your end node, the LoRaWAN library you are using etc. But you are approaching the problem the wrong way. With LoRaWAN, you do not send continuously. Anything. First, it's against the fair use policy anyway. And it would be counter-productive.

What you do is you send a join request. Then you loop, waiting for a result – which can take a little while. Then depending on the result, you send another join request, keeping in mind again the fair use limits, or if the node has joned, you proceed to the rest of your app.

Comment: I use the SX1276 module which uses the STM32L082xx series microcontroller for my project.

My goal is to detect end node is connected to gateway or not, if not than send join request to gateway and also I want to check if connection is broken.

Comment: And I answered how to do this... It all depends on which library you are using. They all have functions to get join status.

Comment: Library which I used is,
- "stm32l0xx_hal.h"
- "LmHandler.h"
- "LoRaMac.h"
- "platform.h"
And many more based on project and STM32